# Check if my database relationship structure is correct

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, relationship

I'm creating database structure but I'm not sure if it's correct.

All functions in my app:

OWNER
- Owner can see all his cities
- Owner cas see all his shops
- Owner can see all users (Assigned and non assigned to the city or/and shop)

CITY OWNER
- Can see all his users
- Can see all shops in "his" city

USERS
- Can see only shops where he is assigned and city where shops come for.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKnVV.png

I added also additional info. (for example in worker I added "owner_id" for easy mysql query but I don't know if i can do this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can get little subjective but still I would say owner, user and workers all are people who are logging into system. Just they have different access levels.

You can store their name and basic info in a single `users` table and have a column `role` which will differentiate if one is an owner or worker etc.

Then have pivot tables owner_worker to map owner to a worker.

Also I think city is an entity should not have have owner Id. You can have cities table and then a pivot table owner_city which lists cities an owner has shop in.